# Replacing punctuation in string in different ways by word length in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a data.frame with a large number of (lengthy) strings. I'm trying to clean them up a little bit before processing them, but I've run into a problem when dealing with periods. I'd like to be able to differentiate between when a period is used to end a sentence and when it's used as part of an abbreviation. I'd like to do this by length of word, but haven't figured out the right regex for it.

Say I have a string like this: `mystring <- "hello.world from the u.s.a."`. I'd like to replace this with something like `"hello world from the usa"`.

I could try splitting the data.frame by spaces using `split_string <- unlist(strsplit(mystring, split=" "))` , and then running something like

`split_string <- ifelse(nchar(split_string) < 7, gsub(".", "", split_string), gsub(".", " ", split_string))`

But as the body of text is rather large, this is a very slow (and rather ugly) process. How could I do this in a more efficient and cleaner manner?

Comment: Not a direct answer but consider preprocessing the strings with `Python` and `nltk` which is far better when it comes to distinguishing between a dot in an abbreviation and as end of a sentence.

Comment: Would it not be better to split on sentences?

Comment: The main problem is that the data is quite messy, and it's difficult to tell where sentence boundaries lie - in `mystring` for instance I'd like to split "hello" and "world" into two separate tokens, but leave "usa" as a single token.

Comment: R has a few sentence boundary detection tools.  I maintain the textshape package that has the split_sentence function to do this.  But this will take some time on longer and or a lot of strings.

Comment: @Jan far better than what?

Comment: You can't understand, ie. parse, language with regular expressions....Its hopeless and impossible.

Comment: @TylerRinker: Than regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this to see if this is any faster.  It looks for a delimiter, up to 6 non-space characters and a delimiter and for any such match it runs the anonymous function specified in formula notation in the second argument of `gsubfn`. That anonymous function removes any periods in the match.  In what is left the `gsub` replaces each period with a space.

```
library(gsubfn)
pat <- "(?<=^| )(\\S{1,6})(?=$| )"
gsub("[.]", " ", gsubfn(pat, ~ gsub("[.]", "", ..1), mystring, perl = TRUE))
## [1] "hello world from the usa"
```

Comment: Great answer! I really appreciate that you made it extendible to any number of non-space characters. Definitely runs faster than a for loop!

Answer (score 2):

How about the following...

```
mystring2 <- gsub("(\\w)\\.(\\w)","\\1 \\2",gsub("\\.(\\w+)\\.","\\1",mystring))

mystring2
[1] "hello world from the usa."
```

For dots either side of letters, it deletes them first, then for the remaining dots with letters either side, it replaces them with a space.

It even keeps the last dot in your example as the end of a sentence!